# Showing function $A \mapsto Ax$ beween normed spaces is bounded

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(X,||.||_X)$ and $(Y,||.||_Y)$ be normed spaces and $(L_b(X,Y),||.||)$ be the space of all bounded linear functions from $X \rightarrow Y$. Let $x \in X$ fixed. How can I show that the function

$$(L_b(X,Y)) \rightarrow Y, A \mapsto Ax$$ is bounded? I could already prove it is linear so if that is needed to show that it is bounded, you can assume it

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of the norm on $L_b(X,Y)$:
$$\|A\|=\sup\{\|Ax\|:x\in X, \|x\|\leq1\}$$
(or something equivalent to this).  Using this definition, you can show that if $x\in X$, we have 
$$\|Ax\|\leq\|A\|\|x\|.$$
Thus, if we let $T_x:L_b(X,Y)\to Y$ denote the map $A\mapsto Ax$, there is some $M$ (namely $\|x\|$) such that for all $A\in L_b(X,Y)$ we have $\|T_xA\|=\|Ax\|\leq M\|A\|$.

Comment: Do you mean $||Ax||=\sup \{||Ax x|| :x \in X, ||x|| \le 1\} \le \sup \{||Ax|| ||x|| :x \in X, ||x|| \le 1\}=||A|| ||x||$?

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote.  Let me clarify a bit.